# Force gson to create new object

Tags: java, gson

Lets say I have a class "Car"

```
class Car{
   @SerializedName("wheels")
   private int wheels;

   @SerializedName("motor")
   private Motor motor;

   // constructor
   public Car{
      motor = new Motor();
   }
}
```

in that case by creating `new Car()` it would create new instance of Motor   `motor = new Motor()`, which is defined in the constructor.

Now I would like to load my "car" from json

```
{
    "wheels": 4,
    "motor": {}
}
```

or just

```
{
    "wheels": 4,
}
```

and then:

```
Car car = gson.fromJson(josnString, Car.class);
```

using this approach it would not create "Motor" object in the class. because {} = null. How could I tell Gson to create a "Motor" object anyway? Should I write my custom deserializer ?

Comment: Not sure but try to initialize Motor object fields with null, might help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was my fault. I figured out:
if using

```
{
    "wheels": 4,
}
```

Object Motor is `null`

if using

```
{
    "wheels": 4,
    "motor": {}
}
```

object is created normally. does not metter if you declare it like `Motor motor = null;`, or just `Motor motor;`